# How can I make PDF with Landscape orientation from an Excel file in Vba Access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pdf, landscape

I used to make pdf file from Access forms using this code:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm,"FR_PFMEAPrint2", acFormatPDF,"PFMEAPrint2.PDF",   True
```

and I printed Excelforms with Portrait orientation in Access using this code:

```
Excel_App.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

and for landscape I used this code in Access:

```
Forms("FR_Print").Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 1, 1, , 1
```

but I need to output Excel file to PDF landscape format via Vba Access Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property of Excel `Sheet` object like shown in the sample  code snippet below:

```
Sheets(1).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
```

Pertinent to your case it will look like:

```
Excel_App.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(1).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
```

or you can iterate through the multiple `Sheets` and set their property in the loop. Also, FYI: you can use underlying `xlLandscape` value of 2.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, But how I make PDF output from this Excel file in Vba Access?

Comment: I would assume that you've already created the reference to the Excel object lib because it seems you were able to print to PDF file using portrait settings (otherwise, you have to add that reference). You should be able to print in the landscape settings based on the solution I've provided. I would appreciate you marking this question answered (the answer is clearly given to you) and if you have additional questions please post them separately. Best regards,

Comment: Alex, I made PDF from Access forms before, but now I want to make PDF from Excel Form in Access and I need the code for that.

Comment: Well, I've clearly answered your question regarding Excel worksheet Landscape orientation while printing to PDF assuming that you've already made all references to Excel Object library from Access VBA editor. By having that, you will be able to create obj vars referencing Excel Worksheet and set their properties as shown in the answer. If you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,

Comment: I run your code, it says "Object does not support this property or method"

Comment: It's because you are doing something wrong. Try to get familiar with Excel VBA basics by reading the documentation pertinent to this case (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-orientation-property-excel). Now, I am closing this communication thread. If you want to get further assistance, please accept the answer and post your questions separately. Best regards,